# Adding a lot of dynamic formatted text to iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, uilabel, uitextview

I have a big issue with my current development stage on a project that I'm working on.

I'm have a UIScrollView which holds 50 multiline UILabels with dynamic content loaded from a localizable.string. The labels are individually formatted (font, bold, italic, color).

The problem is that the App's real memory usage jumps to almost 70MB (live bytes 3MB) and that is just unacceptable and with my current concept I would have to use ~200 UILabels in order to achieve my goal.

What can I do ? Is there a way to lazy load the UILabels or reuse them ? Should I use UITextView or UIWebView ?

How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with [`UITableView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: Are you implying that I should use UITableView ?

Comment: Look at using DTCoreText. It will render really long attributed strings and may be exactly what you need. I use it in my app in the store.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into it right now.

Comment: If you can, I'd definitely use `UITableView`. It would certainly be a better option then using hundreds of UILabels.

Comment: Interesting point of view. I never thought about using UITableView as a text view. Thank you !

Comment: Just to be clear, I meant using one cell per multiline UILabel, not one cell per text line.

Comment: @codeFi On a weird note... was your name... inspired by something?

Comment: @CodaFi :)) When I chose this nick I was thinking at Semper Fidelis because I love to program on Apple platform. Weird coincidence ! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well guys with your help, I've came up with this solution which works just extraordinary !

I'm using a html "template" file with markers inside it and a UIWebView.

Basically what I'm doing is the following:

1. get the html file path.
2. create a string with the contents of html template.
3. replace the markers from the html with my strings (NSLocalized strings - lots of text).
4. load into the WebView contents of the newly created string using "loadHTMLString".

Result: from a memory footprint of 70MB, now I have a memory footprint of 12MB (and that with the equivalent of ~20 A4 pages of text).

Here's the code:

```
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourhtmlfile" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
[_webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [_webView setOpaque:NO];

NSString *htmlBody = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding error:nil];

htmlBody = [htmlBody stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//marker_1//" withString:NSLocalizedString(@"localizedKey_1", nil)];
htmlBody = [htmlBody stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//marker_2//" withString:NSLocalizedString(@"localizedKey_2", nil)];
htmlBody = [htmlBody stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//marker_3//" withString:NSLocalizedString(@"localizedKey_3", nil)];

[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlBody baseURL:baseURL];
```

And now I can use the html goodies like text formatting :D !

I hope that the above will help a lot of people :) !

Thank you guys for support !

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using something like https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel or a UIWebView OHAttributedLabel should have a much smaller memory foot print than a WebView But it depends how many web views you would actually need.

if you use a UIWebView

You'd draw a web view in your view, if you are using IB create and hook up outlets and then in your .m load the html formatted text into via loadHTMLString:baseURL:

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'll look into it. Thank you !